# Find all eigenvalues of the n-order square matrix $A$ in complex number whose all entries equal 1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have tried to start with mathematical induction, but it does not seem to work. Could you please help me? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One eigenvalue is $n$, with eigenvector $v_1=(1,1, ...,1)^T$. The other $n-1$ many eigenvalues are all $0$, any vector perpendicular to $v_1$ is an eigenvector.

Comment: I think one eigenvalue should be n instead of 1. And could you please give a more detailed clarification? Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, the first should be $n$. This matrix maps any vector $u$ to $(u\cdot v_1)v_1$, so if an eigenvalue is not $0$ then the associated eigenvector must be $v_1$.